# How should a closed question that is a duplicate be updated to point at the duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This closed question [Valérios itching cutscene Evil Within](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/284023/153074), appears to be a duplicate of this question [What is happening during this flashback scene from The Evil Within?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/252280/153074).

Both questions are using the same YouTube clip and are both asking why the character is itching when this wouldn't be expected in the timeline that the question asker believes is happening.

It also appears to be the same user, using a different account.

The first question was correctly closed as needing detail or clarity, but it appears to be a duplicate of the second.

Should the first question be reopened, marked as a duplicate and then closed, or should it be left?

Comment: For the record, I saw this question in the review queue and almost closed it as a duplicate. But I didn't because the new question is so unclear that it's hard to be sure if it's a duplicate or not, and both questions have the same OP so maybe they weren't reposting the same question but instead trying to ask a different question about the same scene.

Comment: Are you asking for a general policy or just what we should do about these specific questions? If it's about *policy*, can you offer any other examples?

Comment: If it was "correctly closed as needing detail or clarity" then it can't be a duplicate. In order to be a duplicate it would have to be clear what it was asking; if it is clear what it was asking then it was *not* correctly closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general if you notice a question that is a duplicate of another (especially by the same poster) it's probably best to flag it for moderator attention.  Mods can close a question as duplicate even if it doesn't have an answer, and have additional tools at their disposal.

In a case like this it's probably not a big issue, since the second (duplicate) question is already closed, negatively-scored and unanswered, which means it will get cleaned up by the system in a month or so.  (That it has a negative score, as contrasted to the original, suggests that other users have also noticed the duplication.)

Comment: I didn't notice that it was a dupe. I downvoted because it was an incoherent mess.

Comment: The worst thing was I understood the question perfectly!!

Comment: @A.Steer - Maybe you're just on the same wavelength as OP... or the same meds ;-)